# Getting JSON data based on the item clicked

Tags: jquery, json

I have a search bar which displays a list of couriers and their address which is loaded in from a JSON data file.

When a user enters a postcode, it will display the courier's name and address.

When a user clicks the name or address then it should display the opening times and delivery options. This data is all linked together within the JSON file.

My question is, how would I display the extra json data linked to that item on click?

Currently this is my Jquery displaying the names and addresses

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#search').keydown(function(){
  $('#result').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/m0a3m', function(data) {

   $.each(data, function(key, value){

    if (value.address.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.line1.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.town.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.county.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.postcode.search(expression) != -1)
    {
     $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><div class=""> '+ value.name +' </div><div class=""> '+ value.address.name +'</div><div class=""> '+ value.address.line1 +'</div><div class=""> '+ value.address.town +'</div><div class=""> '+ value.address.county +'</div><div class=""> '+ value.address.postcode +'</div></li>');
    }

   });   
  });
 });

 $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
  $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
  $("#result").html('');
 });
```

Comment: render it to the HTML but set it hidden (e.g. with display:none in the style), then use the click to show/hide the hidden element

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try with this to show the clicked list data information.
you trying to set the data attribute to the list which is shown in Listing time.
Get the data attribute on click function by $(this).data('title'); and get the data one more time if the data is match then display to the html or where you want to display.

```
<div>
     <input type ="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="serachcontent" />
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
<div id="result_open">
</div>
```

```js
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#search').keydown(function(){
  $('#result').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
   var searchField = $('#search').val();
   
   var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  var json_data = "";
 $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/m0a3m', function(data) {
  json_data = data;
  $.each(data, function(key, value){
  /*  console.log(value); */
      if (value.address.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.line1.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.town.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.county.search(expression) != -1 || value.address.postcode.search(expression) != -1){
        $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"  data-title="'+value.index+'"><div class=""> '+ value.name +' </div><div class=""> '+ value.address.name +'</div><div class=""> '+ value.address.line1 +'</div><div class=""> '+ value.address.town +'</div><div class=""> '+ value.address.county +'</div><div class=""> '+ value.address.postcode +'</div></li>');
    }
     });   
   });
  });
 
  $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var index = $(this).data('title');
  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/m0a3m', function(data) {
   $.each(data,function(key,value){
    if(value.index == index){
     $("#result_open").html("<br>Address = "+value.address.county+"  "+value.address.line1+""+value.address.postcode+"<br>Opening Times:- <br> MON :"+value.opening_times.Mon+ "<br>Delivery options"+value.delivery_options[0].description+""+value.delivery_options[0].name+"<br>");
    }
   });
  });
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
    $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
   $('#result').html('');
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<div>
<input type ="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="serachcontent" />
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
<div id="result_open">
</div>
```

Comment: ok but why should we try it? What does it do? How did you solve the problem? Code without explanation is not very helpful for anyone.